# Can't connect to MySQL database hosted in CloudBees

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

I have a free CloudBees account and created a free ClearDB database using their wizards.  My trouble is when I use their connection information (whether I try to connect from my Java app, or an outside tool - SQLyog to be exact) I take the error: Access denied for user 'b51dbc5757d79f'@'%' to database 'mywiki.

The username provided by CloudBees does not contain those extra characters that the error message is displaying which seems like it would be a problem, but I'm not sure there is anything I can do about that since everything is configured for me.  The username I am given is: b51dbc5757d79f - which I can delete and rebuild after sharing here :)

Answer (score 0):

To diagnosis this best way is to be sure you use the right username and password when you connect through a MySQL client like MySQLWorkbench. For that you can use the [CloudBees SDK](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK#HDatabasecommands) and to use the db:info command.

```
bees db:info -p DATABASE_NAME
```

Be sure you don't have any firewall or proxy in the middle of the connection.